# How to access inner object in keystoneJS

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Say I have a model like

```
University.add({
    university_id: { type: Types.Number, required: true, initial: true, index: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: Types.Text, required: true, index: true },
    address: { type: Types.Text, initial: true, required: false, index: false }
});

University.schema.add({
    "inner_object": {
        "name": String,
        "phone": String,
        "comment": String
    }
});
```

I tried updating the object using `getUpdateHandler()`

```
University.model.findOne().where('university_id', universityData.university_id).exec(function (err, university) {
    university.getUpdateHandler(req, res).process(req.body, {
        fields: "name, address, 'inner_object.name', 'inner_object.phone', 'inner_object.comment'"
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ status: false, data: null, message: 'Error while creating university'});
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'University updated successfully', status: true, data: university});
        }
    });
});
```

Iam getting an error **UpdateHandler.process called with invalid field path:  inner_object.name**

Please update if anyone went through the same scenario

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the inner_object outside of keystone, directly through mongoose, which means keystone won't have knowledge about its existence. Just add it to the first configuration object:

```
University.add({
    university_id: { type: Types.Number, required: true, initial: true, index: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: Types.Text, required: true, index: true },
    address: { type: Types.Text, initial: true, required: false, index: false },
    inner_object: {
        name: {type:String},
        phone: {type:String},
        comment: {type:String}
    }
});
```

Comment: How will you add an array of Objects similar to this ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible through keystone. Then you'll have to use schema.add, but you won't be able to update them through the getUpdateHandler, i.e. you'll need to update them manually through mongoose

Comment: Ok. that was the main usecase :(